# Filter certain cases before a certain date

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

In my data frame I need to filter out all men before a certain date. I can manage to filter them into a different data frame, just can't seem to manage to get these cases out of the original one more simply.

```
men <- dplyr::filter(test, !datetime > "2023-07-21 10:22:24" & !geschlecht == 1)
```

Sorry for not providing a dataset, this just seems simple enough to answer without one?

Comment: try with `as.POSIXct("2023-07-21 10:22:24")`

Comment: Just negate it? `test = dplyr::filter(test, !(!datetime > "2023-07-21 10:22:24" & !geschlecht == 1))`

Comment: also, `!geschlecht` should work by itself, you don't need to do `== 1`

Answer (score 0):

Like Maël says, you should convert your characters into date time type and then your can compare it with your date time column (assuming they are? otherwise you also need to convert them first).

Plus, for `!datetime > "2023-07-21 10:22:24"`, why don't you just write

`datetime < as.POSIXct("2023-07-21 10:22:24")`.